# Cannot load data in select 2 jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-select2, codeigniter-2

I want to load data in select2 using ajax on change on text in search filed for that i am using following code but it is not working.There is no error in console and jquery function is not called.

```
jQuery('#t_name').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'get-all_data',
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
            text: item.text,
                        id: item.id
      };
    }
  }
});

public function getAllData()
    {
        $json = [];
        $results=$this->db->select('*')->from($this->user)->get()->result_array();
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
        $json[] = ['id'=>$row['id'], 'text'=>$row['name']];
        }
        return $json;  

    }
```

Comment: is the url correct?

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: The getAllData() is in a php file? the url in your ajax does not point to a php file.

Comment: It is in codeigniter route, it is correct

Comment: I think you need to pass full path in "url: 'get-all_data'" like "url:http://192.168.1.90/projectPath/get-all_data/"

Comment: in your jquery function, log the response and verify whether the data is fetched correctly.

Comment: no i have tried log but no data in console

Comment: When you load your page then this request is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to try something like below:

```
processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.NAME,
                        id: item.ID
                    }
                })
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add base_url of project in your ajax url :

```
    jQuery('#t_name').select2({
      ajax: {
        url: base_url + 'get-all_data',
        processResults: function (data) {
          return {
                text: item.text,
                            id: item.id
          };
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For select2 using ajax need, data in JSON format and also you make a typo mistake in `processResults`.

Please check the below code.

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: 'get-all_data',
        dataType: 'json',
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            }
        }
    }
});
```

PHP Code

```
public function getAllData()
{
    $json = [];
    $results=$this->db->select('*')->from($this->user)->get()->result_array();
    foreach($results as $row)
    {
        $json[] = ['id'=>$row['id'], 'text'=>$row['name']];
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

**UPDATE**

**Suggestion:** Also, You can use this code in PHP function, not need use for loop for date set.

```
public function getAllData() {
    $results = $this->db->select('id, name as text')->from($this->user)->get()->result_array();
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your controller

```
public function getAllData()
{
    //if( $this->input->get('q') != '' ){do something}

    $json = [];
    $results=$this->db->select('*')->from($this->user)->get()->result_array();
    foreach($results as $row)
    {
        $json[] = ['id'=>$row['id'], 'text'=>$row['name']];
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache');
    echo json_encode( $json );

}
```

In your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".select2").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            ajax: {
                url: '<?=base_url()?>/get-all_data',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                cache: false
            }
        });
```

});